# Iterate a dict repeatedly/in a circle/ (simulate the data communication between sensor and data logger)

Tags: python

I am designing a code snippet to replay logged sensor data. Can you help inspire me?
The system works in this way:

- the sensor sends out 11 frames(one value in one frame) every 50ms.
- Randomly start and end data logging

Here is the logged data:

```
dat = {'frame1':[0,1,2,3],
        'frame2':[0,1,2,3],
        'frame3':[0,1,2,3],
        'frame4':[0,1,2],
        'frame5':[0,1,2],
        'frame6':[0,1,2],
        'frame7':[0,1,2,3,4],
        'frame8':[0,1,2,3,4],
        'frame9':[0,1,2,3,4],
        'frame10':[0,1,2,3,4],
        'frame11':[0,1,2,3,4],
        }

Correction: dat1 is from logfile_1, dat2 is from logfile_2, they are continuous from time perspective. 
When start logging, data logger starts to write data into logfile_1, 
the first cycle, data logger received frame7(value '0'), the sencond
 cycle , it received frame8(value '1'), until frame3(value '40'). the
 data logger will continue logging but will start to write data into 
logfile_2 starting with frame4(value '42')

dat = {'frame1':    [5,16,27,38],
        'frame2':   [6,17,28,39],
        'frame3':   [7,18,29,40],
        'frame4':   [8,19,30],
        'frame5':   [9,20,31],
        'frame6':   [10,21,32],
        'frame7': [0,11,22,33,],
        'frame8': [1,12,23,34],
        'frame9': [2,13,24,35],
        'frame10':[3,14,25,36],
        'frame11':[4,15,26,37],
        }

dat2 = {'frame1':    [50,61,72,83],
        'frame2':    [51,62,73,84],
        'frame3':    [52,63,74,85],
        'frame4': [42,53,64,75,86],
        'frame5': [43,54,65,76,87],
        'frame6': [44,55,66,77,88],
        'frame7': [45,56,67,78,],
        'frame8': [46,57,68,79],
        'frame9': [47,58,69,80],
        'frame10':[48,59,70,81],
        'frame11':[49,60,71,82],
        }
```

To make playback working, my solution is to iterate the log file start from frame7 and iterate the whole dict 3 times(use a timer to control the cycle time). At last iterate first 3 frames. How to iterate the dict in this way?
Or do you have a smart solution for this?
Thanks in advance!

### [logfile_1 and logfile_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfXI8.jpg)

update the solution based on Alex's solution 1

```
def mock_sensor(dat):
    i = len('frame')
    end = dict(filter(lambda x: int(x[0][i:]) >= 7, dat.items()))
    center = dict(filter(lambda x: (int(x[0][i:]) < 7) and (int(x[0][i:]) > 3), dat.items()))
    begin = dict(filter(lambda x: int(x[0][i:]) <= 3, dat.items()))
    for frame in end:
        # do something
        print(frame)
        print(dat[frame][0])
        sleep(0.05,1)
    for _ in range(3):
        for frame in begin:
            print(frame)
            print(dat[frame][_])
            sleep(0.05,1)
        for frame in center:
            print(frame)
            print(dat[frame][_])
            sleep(0.05,1)
        for frame in end:
            print(frame)
            print(dat[frame][_+1])
            sleep(0.05,1)
    for frame in begin:
        print(frame)
        print(dat[frame][-1])
        sleep(0.05,1)

mock_sensor(dat1)


output:
frame7
0
298391.1351247
frame8
1
298391.1851848
frame9
2
298391.23526
frame10
3
298391.2853176
frame11
4
298391.335383
frame1
5
298391.3854675
frame2
6
298391.4356516
frame3
7
298391.4857041
frame4
8
298391.5357598
frame5
9
298391.5859605
frame6
10
298391.6360342
frame7
11
298391.6860827
frame8
12
298391.7361375
frame9
13
298391.7863534
frame10
14
298391.8364631
frame11
15
298391.8865663
frame1
16
298391.9366365
frame2
17
298391.9867175
frame3
18
298392.0369269
frame4
19
298392.0870066
frame5
20
298392.1370775
frame6
21
298392.187133
frame7
22
298392.2372161
frame8
23
298392.2873885
frame9
24
298392.337439
frame10
25
298392.3875374
frame11
26
298392.4375916
frame1
27
298392.4876377
frame2
28
298392.5376943
frame3
29
298392.5877566
frame4
30
298392.637998
frame5
31
298392.6880467
frame6
32
298392.7380987
frame7
33
298392.788183
frame8
34
298392.8382282
frame9
35
298392.8882728
frame10
36
298392.938336
frame11
37
298392.9884798
frame1
38
298393.0385387
frame2
39
298393.0885821
frame3
40
298393.1386231
```

Comment: Try using https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat for repeating a sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the most elegant solution but it works okay.

```py
def mock_sensor(dat, first, last):
    i = len('frame')
    end = dict(filter(lambda x: int(x[0][i:]) >= first, dat.items()))
    begin = dict(filter(lambda x: int(x[0][i:]) <= last, dat.items()))
    for frame in end:
        yield end[frame][0]
    for j in range(3):
        for frame in dat:
            if int(frame[i:]) < 7:
                yield dat[frame][j]
            else:
                yield dat[frame][j+1]
    for frame in begin:
        yield dat[frame][3]


def run():
    start = 7
    end = 3
    for j in mock_sensor(dat1, start, end):
        print(j)

    start = end + 1
    end = 6
    for j in mock_sensor(dat2, start, end):
        print(j)


run()
```

Since both `dict` and `list` are mutable modifying the values in `end` or `begin` has the same effect on the values in `dat`.

Comment: Thanks Alex! Explict code is always good to be a solution! Thanks for the comment also, really good to point this out for python beginners like me.

Comment: @XC My pleasure.  I added an alternative and potentially more efficient solution too.

Comment: Thanks Alex, 
first of all, a correct of the dat: frame 7 to frame 11 should not have value '4'.
I have other questions:
I want to playback the logged data. the way is 
1. in the first cycle(50ms), I iterate frame7-frame 11 and yield the first value in each frame which is 0 in this example. 
2. Then I iterate frame1-frame11 three timesand yield one value from each frame at one iteration, in this case, frame1-frame6 will output 0-2 and frame7-frame 11 will output 1-3. 
3. After 3 times iterations, the last iteration is from frame 1 to frame 3 and they output '3'

Comment: another question is i want to playback 5 log files. the data logger will log data continuoutly but when it saves data, it will cut log files to a certain length, for example: each log files contains 50ms x 4 data. In this case, I need to read in logfile_1 and do the iteration and yield sensor data. at the end of logfile_1, it ends at frame3 and I read logfile_2 which starts at frame4 , I need to continue the iteration to yield sensor data.

Comment: @XC If logfile_2 starts at frame 4 that means it isn't a repeat of the first instructions right?  What does it do after starting at frame 4

Comment: I modeified the question, and add exmaples for logfile_1 and logfile_2, i hope this is cleary.

Comment: Thanks Alex, the first solution works well in this case! I updated the result in the qustion description.

Comment: I will update the mock_sensor function to automaticlly find the start frame and end frame. Then this solution can be adapted to different log file situations with different start and end frames

Comment: Where is numbers `20` and `41`?

Comment: I just manfully wrote those number so I made some mistakes . Anyway the idea is to output those data in a linear increase way. As you see the output is correct. Let me make a correction in the data

Comment: You would need to add some parameters to the function so it knows where to start and stop.  kinda like I just did